# Android: Implicit Intents vs. Broadcast Receivers

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm coming up to speed on Android development and the distinction between an implicit intent and a broadcast receiver is unclear.   I was hoping for help in distinguishing these concepts and when to use the two.

Both receive intents, both react to system messages, so why is a broadcast receiver even needed and when is it used as opposed to an implicit intent and intent filter to accept the implicit intent?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Broadcasts are just that -- messages broadcast to anyone listening. They are inherently insecure, and delivery to the intended recipient isn't guaranteed, because there really isn't an intended recipient. For example, the `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast makes this quite clear: When connectivity changes in an Android device, many apps might be interested. Rather than the `ConnectivityManager` having to notify each app via specific `Intent`, it sends a broadcast. Any app that has registered interest in this event will be notified. Any app that isn't running or doesn't care... won't.

An `Intent` is "sent" when one app or `Activity` wants to launch another to do something very specific. For example, a file-manager might want to launch an image viewer or video player. Your app might want to launch a very specific `Activity` within another one of your apps, etc. The communication by specific intents (i.e. including package name and component name) can not easily be intercepted, so it's somewhat more secure. Most importantly, there's only and exactly one "receiver" -- if none can be found, the `Intent` will fail.

Further, a `BroacastReceiver` will be active within an `Activity` or `Service` and received broadcasts will generally only change state and/or do minor UI updates... for example, you might disable a few actions if your internet connectivity is dropped. By comparison, a specific Intent will usually launch a new `Activity` or bring an existing one to the foreground.

Comment: What about implicit intents sent by the OS to anyone listening.  These are the types of intents that at this point seem to me to overlap broadcast receivers quite a bit.

Comment: Implicit intents are not sent my the OS, but rather resolved by the OS. For example, if an app wants to view an Image, any app that's registered to handle image data and the `VIEW` action could receive the intent. The OS will then use the "default" app for this, or, if there isn't one, prompt the user before delivering the intent to *one* app. There is still only *one* recipient for an Intent, while there may be zero or many recipients for a broadcast.

Comment: @user3426948 I think you are comparing two very different things, there's no overlap. An intent is a messaging object, a broadcast receiver is an app component. An intent is used to request some action  from some app component, it could be a broadcast receiver, an activity or a service.
Those implicit intents resolved by the OS like @ 323go says are usually intended to broadcast receivers, perhaps it's there where you got confused?

Answer (score 20):

I am going to compile a list here of all the differences between **Implicit Intents** (sent via `startActivity()`) and **Broadcasts** (sent via `sendBroadcast()`)

1. Broadcasts, by default, can affect multiple applications at once (Ordered Broadcasts have the potential to be disrupted). In contrast, Implicit Intents will only affect one application. *Please note that there may be multiple possibilities of applications that could be affected, but eventually only one will be.*
2. Implicit Intents are handled via **Intent-Filters**, and Broadcasts are handled via **Broadcast Receivers** (albeit the intent-filters play a role here too). *I have seen in many instances over the web that Broadcasts are compared to Intent-filters and that does not make sense to me.*
3. An Implicit Intent launches an Activity, or a Service. By contrast, a Broadcast launches a Broadcast Receiver. (This, if you think about it, is the core difference between Intents and Broadcasts. It is because of this reason that Broadcasts aren't meant to do too much heavy work, and especially not UI work!)
4. From [the Developers Website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> There is no way for a BroadcastReceiver to see or capture Intents used
>   with startActivity(); likewise, when you broadcast an Intent, you will
>   never find or start an Activity. These two operations are semantically
>   very different: starting an Activity with an Intent is a foreground
>   operation that modifies what the user is currently interacting with;
>   broadcasting an Intent is a background operation that the user is not
>   normally aware of.

I'll add more if I find anything else.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A nicely compiled list that explains the differences even better.