# What is the difference between intent filter in activity and broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Can anybody tell me when should I use intent filter and broadcast receiver?

```
<activity>
          <intent-filter></intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
<receiver>
      <intent-filter></intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html):

> A broadcast receiver is a component that responds to system-wide
>   broadcast announcements. Many broadcasts originate from the system—for
>   example, a broadcast announcing that the screen has turned off, the
>   battery is low, or a picture was captured. Applications can also
>   initiate broadcasts—for example, to let other applications know that
>   some data has been downloaded to the device and is available for them
>   to use. Although broadcast receivers don't display a user interface,
>   they may create a status bar notification to alert the user when a
>   broadcast event occurs. More commonly, though, a broadcast receiver is
>   just a "gateway" to other components and is intended to do a very
>   minimal amount of work. For instance, it might initiate a service to
>   perform some work based on the event.

You can use broadcast receiver by two ways.

1) Registering and un-registering in your activity.When you register with your activity you need to pass an action for which it will take care and it will fire when we send broadcast with that action from our application.

2) Second way to use broadcast reciver to register in manifest file and mention action in intent filter for that in manifest file.

Intent filter is nothing but in simple words "It is filter just we use in our usual lives." It will filter the actions for calling it.

Intent filter is same for activity and broadcast receiver.Its main functioning is to filtering the action.It depends on us how to utilize it.One major example is in our each application in manifest file we specify

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

in our launcher activity.It suggests this activity is our launcher activity and will run first at start of our application.If you not specify it then your application will not launch.Also we can not specify these types of filter in broadcast receiver's intent filter.They are not launcher of apps,

Comment: what is the difference between intent-filter in activity and intent-filter in broadcast receiver?

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it. should i use broadcast receiver or activity with intent-filter in case i want to to display a message once the device is booted?

Comment: You can register a receiver which will fire as your device booted.You need to register ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED in your intent filter.As you have context with your broadcast receiver you can show toast message using it.

Comment: Can I achieve the same thing with activity and intent-filter instead of receiver? if so then what is the difference?

Comment: Yes you can call activity when device reboots in which you can show UI means layout and graphical view of your application.But if you only just want to display toast message then broadcast receiver is better option.Again I have already mentioned Intent filter is not different for activity and receiver.It's depends on our requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused about implicit intent and broadcast receiver. Intent Filter in Activity is for receiving implicit intent, while that in Receiver is for receiving broadcast. The OS deliver an broadcast msg to all Receivers, while it deliver an implicit intent to a certain one activity. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445413/android-implicit-intents-vs-broadcast-receivers)